# How to make exact keyword search appear first?

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I made a mysql/php search engine in which I added google url with keywords google search engine and another yahoo url with keywords yahoo search engine. If I type google search engine on the search box how do I make google url appear first?

This is the code:

```
//connect to database
  mysql_connect("","","");
  mysql_select_db("");

   //explode out search term
   $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

   foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
   {

        //construct query
    $x++;
    if ($x==1)
     $construct .= "Keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
     $construct .= " OR Keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

   }

  //echo outconstruct
  $constructx = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct";

  $construct = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct LIMIT $s,$e";
  $run = mysql_query($constructx);

  $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);


  $run_two = mysql_query("$construct");

  if ($foundnum==0)
   echo "No results found for <b>$search</b>";
  else
```

Comment: I hope nobody wants to search for anything with an apostrophe in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To find count of entries, you can use `SELECT count(*)` instead of mysql_num_rows with full query.
2. To sort results, you need to use "ORDER BY" in query, and some field, which will be criteria of ordering. In your case you can write
   `$construct = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct ORDER BY Keywords LIMIT $s,$e ";`

And don't forget to sanitize your $search.
`$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);`

Comment: If I replace the original code with ( $construct = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct LIMIT $s,$e ORDER BY Keywords"; ) i get a ( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a5083847/public_html/search.php on line 52 ) php error

Comment: Won't this just put the results in alpha order based on the Keyword column and not how close the actual match is?

Comment: @Chris Henry, yes, in alphabetical order. `actual match` possible only with fulltext search. I don't know if he uses MyISAM and names of other columns, so I suggest universal variant.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet here is not to use `LIKE`, but to use Mysql's FULLTEXT indexes.  In order to do so, you create a FULLTEXT index on the column(s) you want to search on.

> ALTER TABLE searchengine ADD FULLTEXT(keywords);

To query, do something like this:

> SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ("$searchterm");

You can combine different `MATCH AGAINST` queries to satisfy all the keywords.  Additionally, you can put the `MATCH AGAINST` bit in the `SELECT` clause of your query.  This will return a score that you can then use to rank your results.

Additionally, you can also do some stemming work before even running the query.  Using the scores generated by the various `MATCH` operators, you can rank the entire word higher than the stemmed word.

Comment: SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ("$searchterm");
 This code didn't work.